# Subversion log command doesn't show the most recent revision from almost 10 years ago

Tags: svn

When running the below command on svn 1.7, we get an empty XML log element as output (machine name and credentials changed).

```
D:\vcrs\svn\Collabnet\bin\svn log -r {2008-01-01T00:00:00}:{2019-02-20T10:21:03} --username username --password password http://testmachine:8110/svn/svn/UNITTEST/trunk --xml -v
```

The most recent revision on the trunk for this repository is from 2009-03-10, so almost 10 years ago, but within the requested date. this repository has had several commits to the tags directory every day for the past 10 years (around 9000 in total), but no commits to the trunk. Running the command on the entire svn repository returns these commits to the tags directory. Is there a limitation on how far back Subversion can go with dates?

Update: I've tried the following command with 1.11.1:

```
svn log -r '{2008-01-01T00:00:00}:{2019-02-20T10:21:03}' --username username --password password http://testmachine:8110/svn/svn/UNITTEST/trunk --xml -v
```

It returns the same result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<log>
</log>
```

As requested by bahrep, the output of simply the SVN log command for the trunk:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r886 | (no author) | 2009-03-10 13:19:52 +0100 (di, 10 mrt 2009) | 1 line

deleted readme.txt
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r876 | (no author) | 2009-03-10 10:33:56 +0100 (di, 10 mrt 2009) | 1 line

added extra files and folders
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r3 | (no author) | 2005-11-10 15:38:33 +0100 (do, 10 nov 2005) | 1 line


------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1 | (no author) | 2005-11-10 15:32:07 +0100 (do, 10 nov 2005) | 1 line

Initial import of Subversion Unit Test project
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Update 3: dumping and restoring our Subversion repository has not fixed the issue. Our current train of thought is a corrupt repository, so we're looking into restoring a backup.

Update 4: we've restored a backup for that machine, which fixed the issue on that machine. However, 2 weeks or so ago we replaced that machine from a Windows 2003 machine to a Linux machine, and the issue has today returned for me.

Comment: No, there is no such limitation. Try a supported SVN client version, first. SVN 1.8.x and older is not supported and these versions are actually very old. In year 2019 you should use SVN 1.10 or 1.11 clients.

Comment: @bahrep Could simply accessing with a more recent client cause permanent changes to the repository?

Comment: if this revision was committed to this particular repository, it has to be in place. Revisions are immutable in SVN.

Comment: @bahrep Check update, running it with the SVN command line tools in v1.11.1 doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Do you see this revision when you run `svn log http://testmachine:8110/svn/svn/UNITTEST/trunk`?

Comment: @bahrep see edit. I expect the date command toreturn revision 886 and 876, and it did until this morning. I ran it yesterday with no issues, but this morning it started failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out our subversion repository didn't have monotonically increasing revision dates: at some point repositories went back in time to 6 years earlier. We ended up having to recreate it, because that was easier to do than having to update the revision date of about 300 revisions in our repository.